# D3.js Rotate Vertical Bar Graph Labels

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js and using following example from D3.js to create a simple dashboard for one of my web application.

http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b

My requirement is to rotate top value labels of each bar vertically by 90 degrees.

I changed following method by adding "transform" attribute. Then the labels do not align properly.

```
//Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
        bars.append("text").text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0])+x.rangeBand()/2; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])-5; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(-90)" });
```

I tried to find a solution for long time but couldn't. Links to my codes are given below.

https://jsfiddle.net/vajee555/7udmyj1k/

Can anybody please give me an idea how to archive this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have solved the problem here.

http://jsfiddle.net/vajee555/7udmyj1k/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that when you rotate an element, the `x` and `y` coordinates are changed: they are no longer with respect to that of the chart, but with respect to the new rotated orientation of the element. Therefore, you will need to compute the `x` and `y` attributes differently.

By rotating -90deg, your x axis will be flipped to y, and the y will be flipped to -x:

[image]

I have made some small pixel adjustments to make it appear aesthetically pleasing, such as the `+8` I have added to the y coordinate and the `+5` I have added to the x coordinate, but the fine tuning is up to you.

```
// Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
bars.append("text").text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr("y", function(d) { return x(d[0]) + x.rangeBand()/2 + 4; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return -y(d[1]) + 5; });
```

Also, change how the coordinates are calculated in the `hG.update()` function:

```
// transition the frequency labels location and change value.
bars.select("text").transition().duration(500)
    .text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return -y(d[1]) + 5; });
```

See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7udmyj1k/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
    bars.append("text").text(function(d){ return d3.format(",")(d[1])})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0])+x.rangeBand()/2; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])-5; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform",  "rotate(-90,0,0)" );
```

Change the last line as above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this solution still giving me same results.

https://jsfiddle.net/vajee555/7udmyj1k/4/